# Is it possible to have sub categories in MBUnit?

Tags: c#, mbunit

Right now I use the `FixtureCategory` attribute on my classes to separate my unit tests.

There is one set of closely related tests that are getting too large. I don't want to separate them into their own fixture categories, I just want them to be a subcategory of a larger set of tests. Is there any attribute I can use or another way of doing this?